Redshift Rewriting View Creation Logic
I have created a view in Redshift using the following query:
drop view if exists public.vw_some_table cascade;
create or replace view public.vw_some_table as
(
with interim_table as
    (select
         player_name
       , avg(score) as total_score
     from public.table_1
     group by 1
     )
   , final_table as
    (select
         player_name
       , total_score + 3 as total_score_adj
     from interim_table
     )
select *
from final_table);

However, when I check the view's DDL statement, I see it is stored as follows, using nested subqueries, rather than CTEs:
create view vw_some_table(player_name, total_score_adj) as
SELECT final_table.player_name, final_table.total_score_adj
   FROM ( SELECT interim_table.player_name, interim_table.total_score + 3 AS total_score_adj
           FROM ( SELECT table_1.player_name, avg(table_1.score) AS total_score
                   FROM table_1
                  GROUP BY table_1.player_name) interim_table) final_table;

Is there anyway to prevent this refactoring of the view from taking place? Even if the two output the same results, I would like to retain the business logic as defined using CTEs for easier interpretation/maintenance down the road.

Yeah, use an external source control :) internally they always store the definitions of plain views rewritten, super annoying. At least they keep mat views as they were originally written.
